# Game asset "objects" consisting of several meshes vs continuous mesh

Tags: models, assets, objects

When building game objects in a 3D modeler like Blender I'm finding it's easier to get greater detail and still have fewer vertices if I separate certain elements. For example, I need to make cuts along certain edges to add appendages to that part of the mesh, which could potentially increase the poly count by a large number. If I simply add another mesh I don't need to cut new vertices into the mesh I'm extending. I'm talking about buildings and other structures that never move.

With static objects (that don't move, ever) I was thinking this wouldn't have any drawbacks... but someone may know otherwise. Will this have any visual artifacts or mess up lighting in an engine like Unity or UE4?

Thanks. Sorry if I didn't explain that clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will tell you otherwise: Never leave anything underneath that shall never be visible. 3 reasons:

1. If the rendering for some reason happens from back to front, the hidden surface may get rendered -> consumes fillrate & time.
2. If the hidden suface is closeby underneath, it may cause z-fighting when seen from a slightly longer distance. This is superiorly annoying.
3. Your users get mad when 1, and especially 2, happen.

Apart from these, there may be good logical reasons to divide, but these should be relevant and are outside scope of this Q. On the other hand, multiple meshes -> more code, more housekeeping, more render calls.

I'd say cut the single mesh carefully and group it logically, unless there is a good reason to divide it into multiple meshes (like some need to control the sub-parts individually).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've been very careful to delete faces that are covered up by other faces. I still haven't attempted to import any models that I've made yet because I'm building "modular" meshes that I can swap out different parts of the building. I was mostly concerned with shadow casting effects for "floating" faces that weren't welded into a continuous mesh but I guess I'll find out when I get there.

Comment: Sounds good. Same with shadows, ofc - the normal shadow calculation is based on depth seen from the light source + a calculated depth to the light, from pixels seen from the camera. I take it z-problems there could be equaly bad, if the light source is too far away. Otoh, shadows are usually very local. Would an extraneous face produce a shadow error somewhere... hm, cannot tell right away. Maybe. Nevertheless: Houses are big, may often be seen from distance, so better have the chainsaw handy :-).